# Visual Basic 6.0 in .Net Framework 4.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, frameworks

Will Visual Basic 6.0 supports and work on .Net Framework 4.0?? Please help and suggest me..

Comment: VB6 has nothing to do with .NET. It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Visual basic 6.0 has, and never will be, supported under .net.